# How to have a favicon on my Ember app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I know this seems like a simple question but I've tried many things and nothing seems to be working...

I have `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.jpg">` is my `<head>` tag but the favicon isn't showing.

The path to the image is `\public\assets\images\favicon.jpg`.

No errors whatsoever are shown anywhere.

Any idea why this is happenning and how can I solve it?

Comment: maybe include type="image/x-icon"  after the href=""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by putting the favicon in the assets folder.

i.e.

Moved it from `\public\assets\images\` to `\public\assets\`.